# What site would opt out of the winter bash?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

I see the "Should we opt out of winter bash 2016" Meta posts on all the SE sites I go on. Are there actually any sites that opt out, or have in the past? If so, which ones, and possibly why?

Comment: The arguments "against hats" I've seen fall in two categories: 1. it looks unprofessional, and detracts from the content (much like a pink background would do), and 2. it gives users incentive to game/abuse the platform just to get a hat which will result in low-quality contributions (much like users already do to get rep and badges). I'm not aware of any sites opting out last year though, but a few have done a few years ago (like security.SE).

Comment: Why not opt out? Why follow the following?

Comment: Saying that having a pink background is unprofessional makes Pinkie Pie cry.

Comment: Why is a pink background unprofessional @Carpetsmoker ?

Comment: Hmm. Not on meta.su ...

Comment: @Catija for the same reason people still think that the legendary D&D artifact "+2 Bowtie of Knowledge" really exist. Light travels a lot faster than sound, so often a fast "business" look can cover the lack of contents your words  will bring in only later... That said, I don't think that Carpetsmoker ever implied to actually believe that, probably he just reported the common arguments he heard so asking **him** to back up those claims is a bit unfair.